# Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML') for Vanilla JS Component

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a Vanilla JS Component and I am trying to use the `innerHTML()` function to change the text in a certain ID in the `render()` HTML code. However, I am getting the `Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')` error. I am confused why this error is arising because the ID of the element I am looking for does exist, and the type of the string I am planning to put intto the `innerHTML()` function is a string and is not null type. The code is below

```
class checkoutitemC extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  connectedCallback(){
    const itemName = this.getAttribute('name');
    document.getElementById("nameX").innerHTML=`${itemName}`;
    const price = this.getAttribute('price');
    document.getElementById("priceX").innerHTML=`$${price}`;
    const qty = this.getAttribute('qty');
    document.getElementById("qtyX").innerHTML=`Qty: ${qty}`;
    this.render()
  }
  render(){
    this.innerHTML=`
<li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between lh-condensed">
  <div>
    <h6 class="my-0" id="nameX"></h6>
    <small class="text-muted" id="qtyX"></small>
  </div>
  <span class="text-muted" id="priceX"></span>
</li>
    `
  }
}
```

I tried checking the types of the inputs I was putting into the innerHTML Text and found that to not be null. I also tried simiplying the issue in a seperate HTML file where `innerHTML()` and `getElementById()` do work. This tells me that something with the structure of the component causes this issue.

What are some potential explanations for this weird behaviors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `connectedCallback` method needs to call the `render()` method before it attempts to perform the calculations or set values for elements that do not, at that stage, exist.

```js
class checkoutitemC extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  connectedCallback(){
    this.render();
    
    const itemName = this.getAttribute('name');
    document.getElementById("nameX").innerHTML=`${itemName}`;
    
    const price = this.getAttribute('price');
    document.getElementById("priceX").innerHTML=`$${price}`;
    
    const qty = this.getAttribute('qty');
    document.getElementById("qtyX").innerHTML=`Qty: ${qty}`;
  }
  render(){
    this.innerHTML=`
      <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between lh-condensed">
        <div>
          <h6 class="my-0" id="nameX"></h6>
          <small class="text-muted" id="qtyX"></small>
        </div>
        <span class="text-muted" id="priceX"></span>
      </li>`
  }
}

customElements.define( "checkout-item", checkoutitemC );
```

```html
<checkout-item name="banana" price="123.45" qty="35"></checkout-item>
```

One thing to note with the approach you have chosen with using ID elements and `document.getElementByID` is that you cannot create more than one of these custom items. If you use `this.querySelector('#ID')` rather than `document` it should allow multiple instances.

```js
class checkoutitemC extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  connectedCallback(){
    this.render();
    
    const itemName = this.getAttribute('name');
    this.querySelector("#nameX").innerHTML=`${itemName}`;
    
    const price = this.getAttribute('price');
    this.querySelector("#priceX").innerHTML=`$${price}`;
    
    const qty = this.getAttribute('qty');
    this.querySelector("#qtyX").innerHTML=`Qty: ${qty}`;
    
    this.querySelector('output').textContent='Total: '+Math.abs(parseFloat(this.getAttribute('price')) * parseFloat( this.getAttribute('qty') ) ).toFixed(2);
  }
  render(){
    this.innerHTML=`
      <style>
        li.list-group-item{ margin:1rem; padding:1rem; border:1px dotted grey; display:inline-block; }
        output{ display:block; color:red; margin:1rem 0 }
      </style>
      

      <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between lh-condensed">
        <div>
          <h6 class="my-0" id="nameX"></h6>
          <small class="text-muted" id="qtyX"></small>
        </div>
        <span class="text-muted" id="priceX"></span>
        <output></output>
      </li>`
  }
}

customElements.define( "checkout-item", checkoutitemC );
```

```html
<checkout-item name="banana" price="123.45" qty="35"></checkout-item>
<checkout-item name="apple" price="42.52" qty="15"></checkout-item>
```